# Error in redrawing graph with update function

Tags: d3.js

I'm currently trying to redraw and update my graph every time the slider is moved, which filters my dataset to within that year range. Unfortunately things aren't working properly and I'm unsure where my mistakes are.

When I try to run my code I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

I'm totally lost, any help is greatly appreciated.

Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyab4kcf/11/

Comment: when you declare request_data, you should end this statement with a semicolon not the equal sign. Also the update function should use request_data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this...

```
request_data = data;
```

and this line is referring to the global `year` when it should be the local argument sexYear

```
    var yearData = data.filter(function (element) { return element.YEAR == year });
```

should be

```
    var yearData = data.filter(function (element) { return element.YEAR == sexYear });
```

Also, try the `change` event as well as `input` so it works in IE...

```
d3.select("#sexYear").on("change", function () {
    update(+this.value);
});
```

`this.value` is undefined here because update is called with global `this` context

```
function update(sexYear) { 
    console.log(this.value);
```

you should read these two lines and think about what they are doing...

```
    var ageNames = d3.keys(yearData[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== "CAUSE"; });
    var ageNames = d3.keys(yearData[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== "YEAR"; });
```

I guarantee it's not what you think.

`ageNames` is a very confusing name for this, it should be `seriesNames` for example.  Then you can implement like this...

```
var notSeriesNames = ['CAUSE', 'YEAR']
//...
var seriesNames = d3.keys(yearData[0]).filter(function (key) {
    return notSeriesNames.every(function (e, i, i) { return key != e })
});
```

Finally, you need to fix the UPDATE, ENTER, EXIT structure.  Here is the function with everything fixed...

```js
window.onload = function () {
 console.clear();
 var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 30 },
   width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

 var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .range(["#FD8C25", "#99ABC4"]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x0)
   .orient("bottom");

 var year = 1979;

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y)
   .orient("left")
   .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 var request_data = d3.csv("http://www.sfu.ca/~gdwang/Sex.csv", function (error, data) {

  d3.select("#sexYear").on("change", function () {
   update(+this.value);
  });

  d3.select("#sexYear").on("input", function () {
   update(+this.value);
  });
  update(year);

  // update the year
  function update(sexYear) {
   var notSeriesNames = ['CAUSE', 'YEAR', 'series']
   console.log('update ', sexYear);

   // adjust the text on the year slider
   d3.select("#sexYear-value").text(sexYear);
   d3.select("#sexYear").property("value", sexYear);

   var yearData = data.filter(function (element) { return element.YEAR == sexYear });

   var seriesNames = d3.keys(yearData[0]).filter(function (key) {
    return notSeriesNames.every(function (element, idnex, array) {
     return key != element
    })
   });

   yearData.forEach(function (d) {
    d.series = seriesNames.map(function (name) { return { name: name, value: +d[name] }; });
   });

   x0.domain(yearData.map(function (d) { return d.CAUSE; }));
   x1.domain(seriesNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
   y.domain([0, d3.max(yearData, function (d) { return d3.max(d.series, function (d) { return d.value; }); })]);

   //Cause groups
   //UPDATE
   var causeUpdate = svg.selectAll(".CAUSE")
      .data(yearData),
   //ENTER ****native d3 SIDE EFFECT**** enter selection is added to update selection 
     causeEnter = causeUpdate.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "CAUSE")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.CAUSE) + ",0)"; }),
   //EXIT
     causeExit = causeUpdate.exit().remove(),

  //Series groups
   //UPDATE
     seriesUpdate = causeUpdate.selectAll("rect")
     .data(function (d) {
      return d.series;
     });
   //ENTER ****native d3 SIDE EFFECT**** enter selection is added to update selection 
   seriesUpdate.enter().append("rect")
   //UPDATE + ENTER
   seriesUpdate.attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
   .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.name);
   })
      .transition()
     .attr("x", function (d) {
      return x1(d.name);
     })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
     return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
     return height - y(d.value);
    })
   //EXIT
   seriesUpdate.exit().remove()
  }

  //draw the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
     .attr('transform', 'rotate(-15)')
     .style('text-anchor', 'end');

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Potential Years Lost");

  d3.selectAll(".tick > text")
  .style("font-size", 6);

 })
};
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label for="sexYear" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; text-align: right">
        Year = <span id="sexYear-value">…</span>
    </label>
    <input type="range" min="1979" max="1999" id="sexYear">
```